# Adding Values to playing cards in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to add Values to the cards so i can calculate each players scores.
I would like the scoring system to work like this: 2 has a value of 2 counting up to ace which has a value of 14, ace being highest 2 being lowest. Each suit has another value to it spades = 1, hearts = 2, diamonds = 3, clubs = 2. I think i can do the scoring part myself after i know how to add the values to each card and suit but I have no idea how to add the values so can someone please give me some ideas or hints?

Please no straight up code answers because id like to learn how its done rather than just copy pasting your code.

the deck code is

```
CardList= ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
SuitList= ["Diamonds", "Clubs", "hearts", "Spades"]
Deck= ["%s of %s" %(X, Y) for X in ValueList for Y in SuitList]
```

Comment: This is borderline too broad. There are many possible approaches, and this site is generally not meant as a tutorial service. You want to come here being able to ask concrete questions about some implementation that you have. Can you expand a little bit about what you've tried, sharing your code,    and how it hasn't worked?

Comment: You should really consider using a `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your deck and suitlist to a `dictionary` that way I can tie values to cards and suits.  It's simple, hearts are worth 2 extra points, so `"Hearts":2`.  Then I used the `.items()` function to grab all the item's `keys, values` from the suits list, I stored the value as `v`.  Then, I used `enumerate` to loop over the `CardList`, so I could get both a variable `i` (which is the index of the card in the array) and the name of the card, `X`.   Then I added 2, since arrays start counting at 0.  Finally, I implemented `pprint` in order to make my output look cleaner, you can remove this in the final version.

```
import pprint
CardList= ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
SuitList= {"Spades":1, "Hearts":2, "Diamonds":3, "Clubs":2}
Deck = [["%s of %s" % (X, Y), i + 2 + v] for i, X in enumerate(CardList) for Y, v in SuitList.items()]
pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint(Deck)
```

Output:

```
[   ['2 of Hearts', 4],
        ['2 of Clubs', 4],
        ['2 of Spades', 3],
        ['2 of Diamonds', 5],
        ['3 of Hearts', 5],
        ['3 of Clubs', 5],
        ['3 of Spades', 4],
        ['3 of Diamonds', 6],
        ['4 of Hearts', 6],
        ['4 of Clubs', 6],
        ['4 of Spades', 5],
        ['4 of Diamonds', 7],
        ['5 of Hearts', 7],
        ['5 of Clubs', 7],
        ['5 of Spades', 6],
        ['5 of Diamonds', 8],
        ['6 of Hearts', 8],
        ['6 of Clubs', 8],
        ['6 of Spades', 7],
        ['6 of Diamonds', 9],
        ['7 of Hearts', 9],
        ['7 of Clubs', 9],
        ['7 of Spades', 8],
        ['7 of Diamonds', 10],
        ['8 of Hearts', 10],
        ['8 of Clubs', 10],
        ['8 of Spades', 9],
        ['8 of Diamonds', 11],
        ['9 of Hearts', 11],
        ['9 of Clubs', 11],
        ['9 of Spades', 10],
        ['9 of Diamonds', 12],
        ['10 of Hearts', 12],
        ['10 of Clubs', 12],
        ['10 of Spades', 11],
        ['10 of Diamonds', 13],
        ['Jack of Hearts', 13],
        ['Jack of Clubs', 13],
        ['Jack of Spades', 12],
        ['Jack of Diamonds', 14],
        ['Queen of Hearts', 14],
        ['Queen of Clubs', 14],
        ['Queen of Spades', 13],
        ['Queen of Diamonds', 15],
        ['King of Hearts', 15],
        ['King of Clubs', 15],
        ['King of Spades', 14],
        ['King of Diamonds', 16],
        ['Ace of Hearts', 16],
        ['Ace of Clubs', 16],
        ['Ace of Spades', 15],
        ['Ace of Diamonds', 17]]
```

Comment: This helped me with adding the values, Thanks :) but now that i have implemented that code into my def Generatedeck(): its not letting me shuffle later down in my shufflecards function 

def ShuffleCards():
    shuf = random.shuffle(DL)
    return shuf

Comment: Updated the code, it now uses a 2D list.  Meaning you can shuffle and then access the elements via [0] for card name and [1] for card value.  If you could mark this answer as solution, it would help a lot.